# zoom in and zoom out problems in html page

Tags: html, css, zooming

```
**html**
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" ... />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">  
<div id="header">
<div id="comcast"><img src=Desert.jpg width="18px" height="40px"></img></div>
<div id="menu"><img src=Hydrangeas.jpg width="48px" height="40px"></img></div>
</div>  
<div id="content">      
<div id="content-left"><img src=Desert.jpg width="180px"      height="1000px"></img></div>      
<div id="content-main"><img src=Hydrangeas.jpg width="700px"  height="1000px"></img></div>      
</div>  
<div id="footer"></div> 
<div id="bottom"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>





**css**
body 
{       
 font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;        
 font-size:12px;    
}


#wrapper 
{       

 margin:0px auto;       
 border:1px solid #bbb;     
 padding:10px;  

}

#header 
{       
 border:1px solid #bbb;     
 height:80px;       
 padding:10px;  
}   

#content 
{       
 margin-top:10px;       
 padding-bottom:10px;   
}   
#content div 
{       
 padding:10px;      
 border:1px solid #bbb;     
 float:left;    
}   
#content-left 
{       
width:180px;    
}   
#content-main 
{       
 margin-left:10px;      
 width:700px;   
}   

#footer 
{       
float:left;     
margin-top:10px;        
margin-bottom:10px;     
padding:10px;       
border:1px solid #bbb;      
width:878px;    
}   
#bottom 
{       
clear:both;     
text-align:right;   
}

*{
margin:0px;
 }

#menu
{
float:right;
}
```

The problem is if i do **zoomin** or **zoomout** content left and content main div are jumbling.My requirement is if we do zoom in or zoom out the contentleft and contentmain it should shrink as such and it should not be jumbled.How can i achieve this.

Comment: In which browsers are you testing zooming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before dealing with that issue specifically, you need to fix some HTML suntax/validation issues

```
<img src=Hydrangeas.jpg width="48px" height="40px"></img>
```

should be

```
<img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" width="48" height="40" />
```

1. Wrap attributes in ""
2. Pixels are not reuired in width and height.
3. Remove  and terminate the open tag as />

Comment: I changed the image tag as you specified, but even if i do the zoom in or zoom out my problem is not resolved.